# If statement for search field in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, if-statement

I have a blog site and recently added a search bar for visitors to browse through blog posts. When used, all of the posts go away in the directory and only those which return via the search appear. In order to show the general directory and view all, I would like to have a link appear after the search bar is used to allow this.

I know this could be done with jQuery .click and .show; however, I figured it would be easier if I placed in an IF statement. Similar to how I use `if user_signed_in?` to show links, I was wondering what the method would be for when the search box is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to use a search would be to include a parameter in the URL. That way you can have a similar to `if user_signed_in?` check for the parameter: `if params[:search].present?`.